# Dressing modestly in the summer?

Tags: hijab, modesty

I am hoping for some practical advice about dressing modestly in the summer heat. I've searched a few articles and mostly they only say dress modestly or stay inside, but don't really give specific suggestions. Few things that I am wondering, are for example:

1. What are good fabrics for clothing to wear in the heat which are lightweight and cool but also do not see through?
2. For wearing hijab in the summer, are there styles meant to wear that won't add too much insulation and heat to the head while one is outside in the sun?
3. For exercise in the summer, are there some suggestions on modest workout clothes?

Thank you for any thoughts.

Comment: The islamic requirement for a proper modest dress for women is:  The  whole body should be covered except the face and hands. The clothing must be wide , not to show the body shape.

Comment: Yes I understand that much. What I was asking was practical advice on dressing to that requirement even when it is hot outside, for example sources of modest lightweight clothing as Zia has helped explain below.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. Have a look at the shukr website. There you can find pure cotton clothing islamic style. They are a bit expensive but have a lot on sale too. http://www.shukronline.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cultural dress seems to be the best way to beat the heat in summer. Light silks and thin cotton works for me. I have tried some of the African styles of hijab like the turban for the hottest summer days, and it is also less warm. Try wearing light colours too, black just draws the heat in, white is the best colour for summer.

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

My answer doesnot contain any suggestions. I will try just to cover OTHER side.

So, it all depends on your culture and where you are living, because if i recommend clothes of my country you might not even know their names. Even if you find them and wear them, people will see you as SOME NEW THING. So, any cloth you choose just make sure it comes under definition of clothes in islam. Besides in our country we have COTTON and LAWN like stuff which works pretty well in above 40C in summer.

Now for stuff for hijab, you can use any similar cloth, its common here. Just make sure if its see through, fold it double. BESIDES i am not in favour of styled hijabs, because they doesnot fulfil the purpose of hijab. ALso search about JILBAB(this is what in quran muslims women are ordered to wear) and difference between hijab and jilbab, thats interesting topic too.

Now for your last point on workout clothes, i don't know which kind of workout you are referring to, but i must tell you that exercising or playing in front of men is not allowed. Because whatever you try, you will end up exposing curves etc of your body. You can exercise separately among girls. Where you can wear whatever you want.

### Allah knows best